# RequirePermission not working

Tags: templating, permissions

I'm using the requirePermission tag in the templates for my Craft multisite. I only want users who have access to 'edit' that site be able to view it.

My code is:

```
{% requirePermission('editSite: (currentSite.id)') %}
```

It works fine when logged in as admin, however it returns a 403 for every other user, regardless of their permissions. Please help!

*I'm aware I can use requireLogin but I want users to have access to some sites and not others*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
{% requirePermission("editSite:#{currentSite.id}") %}
```

The way you have it now, the permission it's checking is the literal string `editSite: (currentSite.id)` which no one will have permission for.

**Edit**:

Craft 3.1 doesn't store IDs anymore for permissions, instead it uses always the uids because of the project config. This is a breaking change for many existing projects so keep that in mind.

```
{% requirePermission("editSite:#{currentSite.uid}") %}
```

c.f.: [Twig string interpolation](https://twitter.com/nystudio107/status/938018528527036416)

Comment: Thank you, it still returns a 403 though? Could this be a Craft bug with permissions?

Comment: @Aron15 please see my edit

Comment: Thank you both!